# Count number of times each line repeats itself, In case Insensitive manner

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file like

```
a
A
b
c
```

I want to print number of times each line repeats it self in a case insensitive manner. I found below command to be useful:

```
tr A-Z a-z | uniq -c | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'
```

But it fails if the file is of form `A \n  a`. This gives `2 a`. But the expected output is `2 A`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use `sort` command before using `uniq -c` because this command fails if you have another repeated characters after other characters like input:

```
a
A
b
c
A
a
a
```

And second problem you get wrong result because you convert all  uppercase to lowercase, it cause you getting result in lowercase.

Also you don't need `'s/ *$//'` part of sed because your output has no spaces on end of lines.

You should try with your modified command as this:

```
tr a-z A-Z <file |sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Or even shorter try:

```
sort -r file |uniq -ci
```

`sort` with its `-r` option sorts Uppercase character as first rows. and with `uniq` and its `-i` option ignores differences in case.